Why am I getting different integer results for emscripten and native code?
On a native build, the following code prints -1. Compiled to WASM and run in node.js, it prints 4294967295. Why are the results different?
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned F = 20;
    long HB = 19; // both give -1 if this is `long long`
    std::cout << HB-F << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

This is with g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 as the native compiler and em++ 3.1.66 (1f519517284660f4b31ef9b7f921bf6ba66c4041) for emscripten to compile to WASM.

“Why are the results different?” — They’re not. The web assembly is treating the result as unsigned (but it shouldn’t be, AFAIK).

What are the size / range of unsigned and long on each platform?

My recommendation: never use [unsigned] long type on C++ because you never know if it will be 32 or 64-bit. Use instead [u]int32_t or [u]int64_t.

sizeof(unsigned) == sizeof(long) in WASM like in Windows ABI, and long HB (that has the same size as int) is promoted to unsigned long (which on this platform has the same size as unsigned int).
g++ by default translates the code to a 64-bit binary. In this case sizeof(unsigned) < sizeof(long) and unsigned F is promoted to long int.
Try to invoke g++ with -m32 to get the WASM result.

Indeed, you are correct, -m32 gives the same result as WASM. But is that also a bug, as suggested by NathanOliver's comment on the question referencing https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.rank?

The comment was removed. I don't know what was there. As for WASM specs its native types are like i32, u32.  typedef u32 unsigned; typedef i32 long; may be ES em++ specific.

Can you try std::cout << sizeof(long) << std::endl; on em++?

@SirNate I retracted my comment because I found this which makes me think the behavior in this case is correct.  With the last bullet point of 1.5.3 as the state this example is in.

@NathanOliver thank you for clarifying, it does sound correct given that (unfortunately confusing requirement of the standard).

@3CxEZiVlQ long is 4 bytes.

@NathanOliver So, the result of the subtraction is an unsigned long?  That could perhaps be tested by creating an unsigned long variable before outputting.

"is promoted to unsigned int" in this answer may need to be amended to unsigned long as well.

@MatthewFlaschen Yes.  I suspect unsigned long is the result.  Hold on a sec I should be able to see

Standard C++ requires treating a long as having greater rank than an unsigned,  even if sizeof(long) == sizeof(int), which in turn requires unsigned F to be promoted to long.     This is true regardless of 32-bit or 64-bit builds  i.e.  both should produce a value of type long, equal to -1.     While insufficient information is given in the question to know if g++ is doing the required promotion, it is producing the numeric value that it should.   Whereas WASM - due to producing a large unsigned result - is not.

@MatthewFlaschen Yep, unsigned long: https://godbolt.org/z/EEd4eo13z

@Peter Reviewing Nathan's arithmetic conversion source ("I found this" above): a. "[NO, continue] If [unsigned] has rank greater than or equal to the rank of [long]. b. [DONE if long is 64-bit and unsigned is 32-bit, continue if both are 32-bit]  "Otherwise, if [long] can represent all of the values of [unsigned], C is [long]." c. [C is unsigned long] "Otherwise, C is the unsigned integer type corresponding to S."  It appears all mentioned implementations are correct.

@Peter For b./1.5.3.2, "Otherwise, if S can represent all of the values of U, C is S.", the size does matter.

@Nathan Great research!  You might want to post an answer.

@MatthewFlaschen   The logic doesn't reach that "otherwise" in this case, since the rank of unsigned is less than rank of long.   https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.rank

@Peter While you're correct that "the rank of unsigned is less than rank of long", I don't see anything in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.arith.conv#1.5.3 , including the linked https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.prom , that allows unconditionally promoting unsigned to long in this arithmetic conversion context.

@Peter conv.prom does have "A prvalue that is not a converted bit-field and has an integer type other than bool, char8_t, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank ([conv.rank]) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.", but that doesn't allow promoting unsigned to long.
